# repeating a numpy array a specified number of times for itertools

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, python-itertools

I am trying to write some code that will give me the itertools product, for a varying number of inputs. For example, this works for me.

```
test = np.array([x for x in itertools.product([0,2],[0,2],[0,2])])
```

this gives me my desired result:

```
>>> test
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 2],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 2],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

However, I'd like to be able to be able to pass to the product function a varying number of lists. For example:

```
test = np.array([x for x in itertools.product([0,2],[0,2],[0,2],[0,2])])
```

or

```
test = np.array([x for x in itertools.product([0,2],[0,2])])
```

I have tried

```
test = np.array([x for x in itertools.product(([0,2],) * 3)])
```

and

```
test = np.array([x for x in itertools.product([[0,2]]*3)])
```

but neither gives me the desired result. Surely there is an easy way to do this. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `itertools.product`?

Comment: Its more useful to provide a link when directing someone to the documentation:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: @whitey04: all one needs to do is type `help(itertools.product)` at the console.  And if we're going to link to a specific version of the documentation, at least link to a current version.

Comment: yes I did look at the documentation. I really didn't see anything in itertools that seemed to be exactly what I was looking for, but this seemed o be the most promising.

Comment: @user14241: respectfully, you must not have read very carefully.  The docs say explicitly "For example, product(A, repeat=4) means the same as product(A, A, A, A)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) supports another argument called `repeat` as in `itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat])` through which you can manipulate the dimensions of cross product. Note, this argument should be specified explicitly in order to disambiguate from the list content.

So your example extends to

```
test = np.array([x for x in itertools.product([0,2],[0,2],[0,2],[0,2])])
```

to

```
test = np.array([x for x in itertools.product([0,2], repeat = 4)])
```

Comment: Make sure you specify "repeat"; otherwise it will get confused.

Comment: @whitey04: Can you please elaborate where would you want me to specify?

Comment: ***repeat***=4.  You have to specify the parameter name so it doesn't think its part of the list.

Comment: Perfect. This was exactly what I was looking for. I guess I didn't look at the documentation good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you were grasping for the splat-unpack syntax:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> L = [0, 2]
>>> np.array([x for x in itertools.product(*([L] * n))])
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 2],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 2],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

It may be easier to use the second argument `repeat` to `itertools.product` though.

```
>>> np.array(list(itertools.product(L, repeat=3)))
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 2],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 2],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `*` to expand the list of lists:

```
In [244]: list(itertools.product(*[[0,2]]*2))
Out[244]: [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
```

This expansion, and the use of `repeat` are equal in timing tests.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

**for 3 times**:

```
 test = np.array([x for x in itertools.product(*itertools.repeat([0,2],3))])
```

**for n times**:

```
 test = np.array([x for x in itertools.product(*itertools.repeat([0,2],n))])
```

itertools.repeat([0,2],n) this will repeat elem, elem, elem, ... endlessly or up to n times and * in front of itertools is to unpack all element